# Complex SQL syntax

Tags: django, postgresql, inner-join

I have a game, and in the database I'm saving the user actions by date & time.

```
CREATE TABLE user_actions
(
    aId BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    userId BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(uId) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    aDate TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    aType INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

My users are identified with email

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   uId BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   uName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   uEmail VARCHAR (75) UNIQUE  NULL
);
```

and each day new prizes are added each day has a different number of prizes

```
CREATE TABLE prizes(
   pId BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   pDate TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT now(),
   pType INTEGER NULL
   pSize INTEGER NULL
);
```

This query list the userId and his last action date, per user

```
select distinct userId, max(aDate) from user_actions GROUP BY userId order by userId;
```

I want to create a query that will count the number of prizes added since each user last action.

I'm running:

OS:   Debian
DB:   Postgresql
code: Django

Comment: just post your model definitions and not your table schema in sql

Comment: I think some `INSERT INTO` for each table will be helpful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I will use `CTE` though It has not been tested

```
WITH last_actions AS (
SELECT DISTINCT userId, MAX(aDate) as last_logged 
 FROM user_actions 
 GROUP BY userId ORDER BY userId)

SELECT a.userId, COUNT(b.pDate) 
 FROM last_actions a, prizes b 
 WHERE b.pDate >= a.last_logged      
 GROUP BY a.userId;
```